# How to redirect all urls to a www. subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I've got this rewrite in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^domain.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Which works fine for domain.com but doesn't redirect the URL with something after the /

(domain.com/something.php should redirect to www.domain.com/something.php)

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check it out

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Comment: You sir, get a +1 and an accepted answer!! thank you very much!

Comment: One more question, can you think of a way to make an exception for all the URLs that already have a subdomain, say: blog.domain.com (because they are not working now) maybe this should be a whole different question, I don't know. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

My guess its because you write `^domain.com/$` - the dollar sign at the end means end of the string, so nothing can be after it - that is why it works with domain.com, but does not work with something more?

Comment: Well, yes... that is my problem :)

Comment: My indirect suggestion was to remove the `$` at the end ;)